# Filter nested array with conditions based on multi-level object values and update them - MongoDB aggregate + update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, pymongo

**Considering I have the following documents in a collection** (ignoring the `_id`) **:**

```
[
  {
    "Id": "OP01",
    "Sessions": [
      {
        "Id": "Session01",
        "Conversations": [
          {
            "Id": "Conversation01",
            "Messages": [
              {
                "Id": "Message01",
                "Status": "read",
                "Direction": "inbound"
              },
              {
                "Id": "Message02",
                "Status": "delivered",
                "Direction": "internal"
              },
              {
                "Id": "Message03",
                "Status": "delivered",
                "Direction": "inbound"
              },
              {
                "Id": "Message04",
                "Status": "sent",
                "Direction": "outbound"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "Conversation02",
            "Messages": [
              {
                "Id": "Message05",
                "Status": "sent",
                "Direction": "outbound"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "Session02",
        "Conversations": [
          {
            "Id": "Conversation03",
            "Messages": [
              {
                "Id": "Message06",
                "Status": "read",
                "Direction": "inbound"
              },
              {
                "Id": "Message07",
                "Status": "delivered",
                "Direction": "internal"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "Conversation04",
            "Messages": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "OP02",
    "Sessions": [
      {
        "Id": "Session03",
        "Conversations": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "OP03",
    "Sessions": []
  }
]
```

---

### First query — aggregate (+`$project`)

I want to get the list of **`Messages`** grouped by their **`Conversations`** where:

- `Sessions.Id: "Session01"`

**and**

- `Sessions.Conversations.Messages.Direction $in ["inbound", "outbound"]`

**and**

- `Sessions.Conversations.Messages.Status $in ["sent", "delivered"]`

**The expected result is:**

```
[
  {
    "Id": "Conversation01",
    "Messages": [
      {
        "Id": "Message03",
        "Status": "delivered",
        "Direction": "inbound"
      },
      {
        "Id": "Message04",
        "Status": "sent",
        "Direction": "outbound"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "Conversation02",
    "Messages": [
      {
        "Id": "Message05",
        "Status": "sent",
        "Direction": "outbound"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

***A side note:***

*If on different `documents` (or on different `Sessions`) the `Sessions.Id: "Session01"` condition is verified (**`"Session01"`is not an unique key**), the `document`'s `Messages` that match the other conditions should also be added.*

***The result output doesn't mention neither the `document` or `Sessions` levels.***

---

### Second query — update

I want to **update the `Sessions.Conversations.Messages.Status`** of all those messages *(same condition as before)* to **`"read"`**.

**The collection should have now the following documents:**

*Please note the changes on:*

- `Sessions.Conversations.Messages.Id = "Message03"`
- `Sessions.Conversations.Messages.Id = "Message04"`
- `Sessions.Conversations.Messages.Id = "Message05"`

*at* `Sessions.Id = "Session01"`

```
[
  {
    "Id": "OP01",
    "Sessions": [
      {
        "Id": "Session01",
        "Conversations": [
          {
            "Id": "Conversation01",
            "Messages": [
              {
                "Id": "Message01",
                "Status": "read",
                "Direction": "inbound"
              },
              {
                "Id": "Message02",
                "Status": "delivered",
                "Direction": "internal"
              },
              {
                "Id": "Message03",
                "Status": "read",
                "Direction": "inbound"
              },
              {
                "Id": "Message04",
                "Status": "read",
                "Direction": "outbound"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "Conversation02",
            "Messages": [
              {
                "Id": "Message05",
                "Status": "read",
                "Direction": "outbound"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "Session02",
        "Conversations": [
          {
            "Id": "Conversation03",
            "Messages": [
              {
                "Id": "Message06",
                "Status": "read",
                "Direction": "inbound"
              },
              {
                "Id": "Message07",
                "Status": "delivered",
                "Direction": "internal"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "Conversation04",
            "Messages": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "OP02",
    "Sessions": [
      {
        "Id": "Session03",
        "Conversations": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "OP03",
    "Sessions": []
  }
]
```

---

How can I accomplish these results with an **`aggregate`** and **`update_one`** queries?

---

Here comes a visual explanation of both queries:

[image: Explanation of queries]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written the aggregation query

```
        db.session.aggregate([
          {
            $unwind:"$Sessions"
          },
          {
            $unwind:"$Sessions.Conversations"
          },
          {
            $unwind:"$Sessions.Conversations.Messages"
          },
          {
            $match:{
              "Sessions.Id" : "Session01",
              "Sessions.Conversations.Messages.Direction":{
                $in:[
                  "inbound", "outbound"
                ]
              },
              "Sessions.Conversations.Messages.Status":{
                $in:[
                  "sent", "delivered" 
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $group:{
              "_id":"$Sessions.Conversations.Id",
              "Messages":{
                $push:"$Sessions.Conversations.Messages"
              }
            }
          }
        ]).pretty()
```

**Output**

```
        {
                "_id" : "Conversation02",
                "Messages" : [
                        {
                                "Id" : "Message05",
                                "Status" : "sent",
                                "Direction" : "outbound"
                        }
                ]
        }
        {
                "_id" : "Conversation01",
                "Messages" : [
                        {
                                "Id" : "Message03",
                                "Status" : "delivered",
                                "Direction" : "inbound"
                        },
                        {
                                "Id" : "Message04",
                                "Status" : "sent",
                                "Direction" : "outbound"
                        }
                ]
        }
```

Now to Update the document:

I have used the [positional-filters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

```
        db.session.update(
          {},
          {
            $set:{
              "Sessions.$[session].Conversations.$[].Messages.$[message].Status":"read"
            }
          },
          {
            "arrayFilters": [{"session.Id":"Session01"},{ "message.Id": "Message05" }] 
          }
        )
```

This will update the status as `read` for `"session.Id":"Session01"` and `"message.Id": "Message05"`

Hope this will help you. :)

**UPDATE**

```
        db.session.update(
          {},
          {
            $set:{
              "Sessions.$[session].Conversations.$[].Messages.$[message].Status":"read"
            }
          },
          {
            "arrayFilters": [
              {
                "session.Id":"Session01"
              },
              { 
                "message.Direction": {
                  $in :[
                    "inbound", 
                    "outbound"
                  ]
                },
                "message.Status": {
                  $in :[
                    "sent", 
                    "delivered"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ] 
          }
        )
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I have updated my answer according to the aggregate filters.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :)

Comment: Implementing your solution I detected a new question: in the ```$group``` I can't add more fields such as the ```"_id":"$Sessions.Conversations.Id"```. Let's say that ```Sessions.Conversation``` has one more key ```"Info"``` that is an object. I can't write ```info: "$Sessions.Conversations.Info"``` - **result:** ```The field 'info' must be an accumulator object```

Comment: You need to add an object in ```_id``` eg:
``` {$group:{"_id":{"Id":"$Sessions.Conversation.Id","info":"$Sessions.Conversation.info"}}}```

Comment: I fixed it with ```"info":{"$first":"$Sessions.Conversation.info"}```

Comment: ooh I thought you want to group on multiple values :)