# Filter by nested arrays/objects values (on different levels) and $project by matching groups (on a specific level) - MongoDB Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Considering I have the following collection (ignoring documents `_id`):

### Collection

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Level2": [
      {
        "Id": "1.1",
        "Level3": [
          {
            "Id": "1.1.1",
            "Level4": [
              {
                "Id": "1.1.1.1",
                "Status": "a"
              },
              {
                "Id": "1.1.1.2",
                "Status": "b"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "1.1.2",
            "Level4": [
              {
                "Id": "1.1.2.1",
                "Status": "a"
              },
              {
                "Id": "1.1.2.2",
                "Status": "c"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "1.1.3",
            "Level4": [
              {
                "Id": "1.1.3.1",
                "Status": "c"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Level2": [
      {
        "Id": "2.1",
        "Level3": [
          {
            "Id": "2.1.1",
            "Level4": [
              {
                "Id": "2.1.1.1",
                "Status": "a"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

### Conditions

**I want to query it such as:**

- `Level2.Id: "1.1"`
- `Level2.Level3.Level4.Status $in ["a", "b"]`

**The `$project`  should:**

- **Group** `Level2.Level3.Level4` matches by `Level2.Level3`
- Should not include `Level2.Level3` if it is an **empty array**

---

**The expected result should be:**

### Result 1

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1.1.1",
    "Level4": [
      {
        "Id": "1.1.1.1",
        "Status": "a"
      },
      {
        "Id": "1.1.1.2",
        "Status": "b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "1.1.2",
    "Level4": [
      {
        "Id": "1.1.2.1",
        "Status": "a"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

**Please notice that if current `Level2.Id: "2.1"`  has the value `"1.1"` instead, the result should be** (matches on different documents)**:**

### Result 2

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1.1.1",
    "Level4": [
      {
        "Id": "1.1.1.1",
        "Status": "a"
      },
      {
        "Id": "1.1.1.2",
        "Status": "b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "1.1.2",
    "Level4": [
      {
        "Id": "1.1.2.1",
        "Status": "a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "2.1.1",
    "Level4": [
      {
        "Id": "2.1.1.1",
        "Status": "a"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

How can I accomplish this with an **`aggregate` query?**

*( filtering different levels and grouping by some level )*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter nested array with conditions based on multi-level dictionaries values and update them - MongoDB aggregate + update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157587/filter-nested-array-with-conditions-based-on-multi-level-dictionaries-values-and)

Comment: That question was also posted by me. Although It focus on a different type of problem (that contains this one) while this one is not so well formally expressed. I left both questions because probably is more simple to find a quick answer for this one as well as future searches on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here it is the answer** (thank you to @Vijay Rajpurohit for his help on this):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$Level2"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Level2.Level3"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Level2.Level3.Level4"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "Level2.Id": "1.1",
      "Level2.Level3.Level4.Status": {
        $in: [
          "a",
          "b"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$Level2.Level3.Id",
      "Messages": {
        $push: "$Level2.Level3.Level4"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**The result of this query is:**

```
[
  {
    "Messages": [
      {
        "Id": "1.1.2.1",
        "Status": "a"
      }
    ],
    "_id": "1.1.2"
  },
  {
    "Messages": [
      {
        "Id": "1.1.1.1",
        "Status": "a"
      },
      {
        "Id": "1.1.1.2",
        "Status": "b"
      }
    ],
    "_id": "1.1.1"
  }
]
```

### [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YyA6d9Qj9Sf)